# Filtering null values when != and == are overloaded

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have overloaded the != and == operators of an entity type. Now, when I run :

```
dbContext.MyEntityDbSet.Where(x => x.MyProperty != null)
```

I'm getting an exception saying

> Cannot compare elements of type 'MyEntityType'. Only primitive types,
>   enumeration types and entity types are supported.

How can I bypass it ?

Thank you

Comment: Good point, sorry about that ! Actually I'm checking a property of my class, I'll fix that

Comment: Since you're using a query provider the fact that you've overloaded the `!=` operator is irrelevant.  That overload isn't being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF does not know that == and != are overloaded. You can also compare primitive types. Also, you cannot compare 2 entities of same type (it could compare them comparing primary Keys like hibernate does). So you need to replicate == and != also in LINQ query (or materialize - i.e. insert a ToList() - the query before the Where but this is a very bad solution).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, actually the point is I don't want to replicate this behaviour in my query. I simply want to check if the foreign key associated with this property is null, however it looks like EF actually knows that the operators are overloaded and tries to use them

Comment: When writing this comment, I realized that I could perhaps do a check on the value of the foreign key. But this is not an ideal solution as my model doesn't contains foreign keys now and I would like to avoid introducing them if possible.

Comment: If you need to check an entity (also a related entity) you need to check the primary key, i.e. x.Id == null. Also, If you implement == in x you can't check x == null.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in my question.  As I said previously, ideally I would like not to introduce foreign keys. Also, for your last statement you can do it with : ((object)x).Equals(null)

Comment: @red2nb Your statement that EF knows that the operator is overloaded and tries to use it is false.  It's translating all this to SQL, not running it as C# code.

Comment: @Servy thank you, I'll look in an other direction then. I've found a workaround very specific to my query and its context, but I'll continue to think about it and let you know if I find the real cause of the issue. I accept this answers since it addressed my misconception

Answer (score -1):

Possibly the best way to do this is to cast your parameter to a generic without the overload:

```
dbContext.MyEntityDbSet.Where(x => (object)x != null);
```